# VB.NET NullReferenceException Timer.Start()

Tags: vb.net

Me salta el siguiente error, y no entiendo el motivo...

He cambiado el acceso a Public de todos los timers por si ese era el problema y nada...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
'Block timers
Private Sub blocktimers()
    Dim i As Integer
    For Each c As Timer In Me.components.Components
        If TypeOf c Is Timer Then
            If c.Enabled And c.Interval <> 210 Then
                carray(i) = c
                ReDim Preserve carray(i + 1)
                c.Stop()
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

'Release timers
Private Sub releasetimers()
    For Each c As Timer In carray
        c.Start()
    Next
End Sub
```

Revisando punto a punto, he visto que en algún momento detecta c con el valor Nothing.

He añadido un If c IsNot Nothing Then, antes de c.Start()

Ahora no salta el error y la aplicación no se atasca pero si pongo un punto de interrupción en cada sub, veo que releasetimers() solo me activa 1 timer, el valor del segundo timer que encuentra es nothing y sale del sub, mientras que blocktimers() está deteniendo más de 10 timers...

Un saludo y muchas gracias!

Comment: Lo que pasa es que cuando asignas c del carray en el for, se asigna una copia y no a una referencia y se lo cambias a la copia. Tienes que asignarselo directamente al array del for, haciendo la asignacion carray(c.index) o algo parecido es que no lo puedo probar ahora pero lo que te esta pasando es eso, que se lo asignas a una copia.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que cuando asignas c del carray en el for, se asigna una copia y no a una referencia y se lo cambias a la copia. Tienes que asignarselo directamente al array del for, haciendo la asignacion carray(c.index) o algo parecido es que no lo puedo probar ahora pero lo que te esta pasando es eso, que se lo asignas a una copia.

Comment: Exactamente, tenía que agrandar i y después meterlo dentro del array.